# Send cookies/site login information over my internal network?

Tags: linux, networking, google-chrome, cookies, packet

Is there a way I can send cookies/site login information to computers within my internal network? i.e push them through in packet headers? Not FTP.

For example if I want to send cookies with my shopping cart or login information from one computer to another within my network how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you clarify the desire for adding them as packet headers? What is wrong with just providing access to them from other computers? Do you just want one set of cookies/stored passwords to cache to the rest of the computers on the network? Why not just have a batch script that runs periodically that copies from one computer to all others on the network? or one that copies to a central location that all the other computers copy off of?

Comment: How would I implement copying it from one computer to all others on the network?

Comment: batch script: xcopy "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox" "\\server\folder" /e /v /c /h /r /y  -  this will copy your firefox profile to a network folder, reverse it and run it on another machine to copy it to that machine. One machine runs this, every other runs the reverse and all the machines will have the same profile as a whole. I use this to back up my FF profile at work and home. It is nice at work because I can go to another computer for a meeting and just pull my profile off easily and have all my FF data present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firefox** - Full profile (addons, bookmarks, cookies)

This goes on the machine that you want the master profile on:

```
xcopy "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox" "\\server\FF\" /e /v /c /h /r /y
```

This goes on the machines that you want to pull the profile from:

```
xcopy "\\server\FF\" "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox" /e /v /c /h /r /y
```

**Internet Explorer** - Cookies and Bookmarks

This goes on the machine that you want the master profile on:

```
xcopy "%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies" "\\server\IE\cookies" /e /v /c /h /r /y
xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites"  "\\server\IE\Bookmarks" /e /v /c /h /r /y
```

This goes on the machines that you want to pull the profile from:

```
xcopy "\\server\IE\" "%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies" /e /v /c /h /r /y
xcopy "\\server\IE\Bookmarks" "%USERPROFILE%\Favorites" /e /v /c /h /r /y
```

Put what you want in a batch script, set scheduler to run as often as desired. With this method you will always have a backup and all your computers will share the same profile data.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of cookies : [HTTP cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) and [Flash cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_cookies) (Local Shared Objects - LSO).

**HTTP cookies** are normally stored as text files (IE) or as a database (Firefox), in the following directories.

**IE** : `C:\Users\{USER-NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies`
**Firefox** : `C:\Users\{USER-NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{profile}.default\cookies.*`

**Flash cookies** are stored in (Vista and up) :
`C:\Users\{USER-NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\{profile}\{website}`
or (XP) :
`C:\Documents and Settings\{USER-NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\{profile}\{website}`

Sharing in a local network would be by sharing the lead-computer's cookie directories over the network, so they can be copied (all or selectively) to the other computers. It would not be a good idea to try and set one directory for use by all the network computers, because you would then risk losing them all.

This is easiest for IE because each cookie is a text file.
For Firefox this is an all-or-nothing operation, since the cookies are stored in an SQLite database, or one can use extensions such as [Export Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/) and [Cookie Importer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-importer/).

Sharing over the Web is either via a file-sharing website such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) or a file-sharing product such as [Windows Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh).

<sub>(I have not covered Chrome here, but there are doubtlessly equivalents to the above)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You would have to locate the cookies that are responsible for this manually, and the transfer them over to your other computers, and then place them in the right folder. If you give your browser information, I could give you more specifics.

Comment: So there is no way I can just send them over the network, even if I open specified ports? I already have the cookie information.

Comment: Well, its a file transfer. If you want to do that though making the required folders part of a network share or something, or FTP it over, that will work.